# GraalVM Native Image Manual Proxy Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-native, paketo

We migrated an appication to GraalVM docker image, Building a Native Image Using Buildpacks. The application previously running on JDK 8 and Spring boot 2.2.0.RELEASE. We migrated to JDK-17 and SpringBoot 3.0.2 as GraalVM latest prerequisite. The image has been build successfully, but while trying to run the container we are the below error

```
2023-02-17 11:18:10,233 ERROR [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exposeAttemptedPathAuthenticationAuditListener': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.abc.cefg.iom.App.main(Application.java:7)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Proxy class defined by interfaces [interface jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] not found. Generating proxy classes at runtime is not supported. Proxy classes need to be defined at image build time by specifying the list of interfaces that they implement. To define proxy classes use -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=<comma-separated-config-files> and -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=<comma-separated-config-resources> options.
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.proxy.DynamicProxySupport.getProxyClass(DynamicProxySupport.java:171)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:47)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils.resolveAutowiringValue(AutowireUtils.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArguments(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:206)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

As new to graalvm native images, don't know whether need to configure the proxies in config files or something to tell AOT compiler to take into consideration

Need to run the graalvm docker continer succssfully

Answer (score 0):

When building the native image, the image has been built by AOT compilation hence we need to tell about the proxy, serialization related resources to the compiler at the build-time of the image. We can use the below class to provide the hint to the compiler

```
public class RuntimeHint implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {
            @Override
            public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hints, ClassLoader classLoader) {
                try {
                    ProxyHints proxies = hints.proxies();
                    proxies.registerJdkProxy(HttpServletRequest.class);
                    ResourceHints resourceHints = hints.resources();
                    resourceHints.registerPattern("schema.graphqls");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not register RuntimeHint: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Got the answer with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829933/spring-boot-3-0-0-graavm-for-interface-jakarta-servlet-http-httpservletrequest)